# inheritance and polymorphism print function

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

i have this function :

```
void f(const A& a){a.print()};
```

and a class:

```
class A { 
void print() const{cout<<"a"<<endl;}
}
```

in the first section i want my code to print b using inheritance without changing the print function. 
i tried implementing new class `B` which inherits from `A` . and my code printed b.
now in the second section i need to change only this line : `void f(const A& a)` and my code should print a.
how can i do so?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class A{
protected:
    string a;
public:
    A(string a):a(a){}
    virtual void print()const{
        cout<<"a"<<endl;
    }
    virtual ~A(){}

};
class B:public A{
    //string b;
public:
    B(string b):A(b){}
    virtual void print()const{
        cout<<"b"<<endl;
    }
    virtual ~B(){}

};
void f(const A& a){
    a.print();
}
int main(){
    B a=B("b");
    f(a);
    return 0;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed copy the base class subobject as described in other answers. But you don't need to and it usually makes more sense to use static dispatch:

```
a.A::print();
```

Of course, this modifies a line other than the declaration of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this effect by passing the parameter by value

```
void f(A a);
```

That way the function will receive a copy of the `A` part of any class derived from `A`.

This is sometimes done by mistake (see [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)), but gets the job done here.

Comment: what should i do if i want the code to print c now only by changing the same line and add something to class A

Comment: @rawan - That is another question. One question per question, please.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to avoid the virtual call, you need a new object of type A...

you can use pass the parameter by value or create a copy of type A inside the function f:

```
void f(const A& a) {
    A tmp(a);
    tmp.print()
}
```